# Mongoose - what is this validation validating?

Tags: mongoose

Whilst following [this](http://blog.kevinblanco.io/creating-a-simple-crud-with-node-js-express-mongodb-and-angularjs-part-1/) tutorial, I come to step 5 (which I adapted to fit my own app )

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Unit = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    screenName: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    position: {
        type: [Number],
        require: true
    },
    imagePath: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
});

Unit.path('model').validate(function(v) {
    return ((v!="") && (v!= null));
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Unit', Unit);
```

...which gives me `TypeError: Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined` when I try to start my server.

Removing the validate block allows everything to run fine.

But what is the block actually doing? Validating the "path" of the Unit model? What path?
Nothing in [the mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) gives me any sort of guidance.

Comment: Have you looked at [validation section](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) of mongoose docs?

Comment: And [here is a corresponding API doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is adding a custom validation function to the `model` field (aka [path](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-path)) of the `Unit` schema.  But that schema doesn't have a `model` field so the call to `Unit.path('model')` returns `undefined`, causing the `TypeError` you see.

The validation function is sort of an enhanced `require: true` validator example that also disallows empty strings and null values.

Comment: [Original schema](http://blog.kevinblanco.io/creating-a-simple-crud-with-node-js-express-mongodb-and-angularjs-part-1/#5definingtheappmodels) had `model` path. OP changed the schema, but left the validation intact.

Comment: So 'path' here means 'field' or 'property' or 'key', and the validation is simply for the presence of this property? Doesn't the require: true already handle that validation for all the keys anyway?

Comment: @dwilbank Right, I suppose it's sort of an enhanced `require: true` validator example that also disallows empty strings and null values.